# I installed intel graphic drivers and now can't interact with my system. What can I do?

Tags: drivers, grub2, graphics, intel

I have a

```
System:    Host: *** Kernel: 5.0.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0 Console: tty 0
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-AAC11 v: 1.0 serial: N/A UEFI: American Megatrends v: 8.00 date: 04/18/2017
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-7100 (-MT-MCP-) arch: Skylake rev.9 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 15648
           clock speeds: max: 3900 MHz 1: 1143 MHz 2: 3045 MHz 3: 3526 MHz 4: 3560 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 630 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: N/A drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           tty size: 135x47 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
```

and graphic performance was very poor. So, when I looked at this `inxi`output, I realized, that seemingly no intel drivers were loaded. So I had the idea to `apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.
This removed quite a bit of other stuff (unfortunately, I did this with apt on a ssh session, so maybe I haven't got the whole output).

```
(Reading database ... 309003 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing lubuntu-gtk-core (0.94.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 (1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 (19.0.1-1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04 (1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04 (1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 (1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-all (1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 (0.28.1-1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 (1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 (1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 (2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 (1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 (0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 (1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-core.
(Reading database ... 308826 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-intel.
Preparing to unpack .../xserver-xorg-video-intel_2%3a2.99.917+git20171229-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20171229-1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20171229-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Now, the system still boots, but the de login screen does not allow any inputs, neither mouse nor keyboard. The cursor is blinking, though. I cannot reach a tty and I have no network connection (as seen from the router).

Pressing `esc` during boot brings me to a working grub console, that is the best in interactivity I could evoke. `Shift` does not seem to do anything, so at least that way I cannot get to a safe boot option or anything alike.

How should I continue from here?

Comment: Reinstall the system and don't do stupid things like "installing Intel drivers" again. That's the easiest solution. You broke your system by installing a package from a wrong stack. If you manage to boot to a safe mode with console available, you can try to fix it by `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

Comment: Any idea, how I could tell grub to start a safe boot?

Comment: You should get to grub menu, not to console by pressing ESC. It is much easier and faster to re-install the system now, compared to investigate the grub problems without any guarantee it will finally fix anything.

Comment: If you can get to Recovery Mode **with network**, or a console mode with ctrl-alt-f2, you *could* try using apt or apt-get to remove the package that you installed, and reinstall the packages that got removed. It won't be fun... and if that doesn't work, you'll have to reinstall the system.

Comment: In the end I really did uninstall, but safeguarded the home directory, so after setting up another distribution, setting up users while keeping all configurations was trivial.